# Uncaught exception with onListItemClick using parcelable

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an Uncaught exception with onListItemClick using parcelable and I have exhausted all avenues possible in search of an answer. The app is a birdwatching app that uses a standard listview with a custom adapter which links to a detail activity. The birds and their details are stored locally using SQLite. Any help much appreciated..

Just to add.. this is my first app and first post here, so be kind..

Here is my onListItemClick method:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Bird bird = birds.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
    intent.putExtra(".model.Bird", bird);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is my Profile class:

```
public class Profile extends Activity{

Bird bird;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    bird = b.getParcelable(".model.bird");

    refreshDisplay();

}
```

And here is my model (without setters and getters):

```
public Bird() {
    super();
}

public Bird(Parcel in) {
     //Log.i(ReferenceGuide.LOGTAG, "Parcel constructor");

     id = in.readLong();
     name = in.readString();
     latin_name = in.readString();
     description = in.readString();
     habitat = in.readString();
     diet = in.readString();
     breeding = in.readString();
     wintering_habits = in.readString();
     where_to_see = in.readString();
     conservation = in.readString();
     image = in.readString();
     primary_colour = in.readInt();
     secondary_colour = in.readInt();
     crown_colour = in.readInt();
     bill_length = in.readInt();
     bill_colour = in.readInt();
     tail_shape = in.readInt();
     created_at = in.readString();
     upated_at = in.readString();
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
     //Log.i(ReferenceGuide.LOGTAG, "writeToParcel");

     dest.writeLong(id);
     dest.writeString(name);
     dest.writeString(latin_name);
     dest.writeString(description);
     dest.writeString(habitat);
     dest.writeString(diet);
     dest.writeString(breeding);
     dest.writeString(wintering_habits);
     dest.writeString(where_to_see);
     dest.writeString(conservation);
     dest.writeString(image);
     dest.writeInt(primary_colour);
     dest.writeInt(secondary_colour);
     dest.writeInt(crown_colour);
     dest.writeInt(bill_length);
     dest.writeInt(bill_colour);
     dest.writeInt(tail_shape);
     dest.writeString(created_at);
     dest.writeString(upated_at);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Bird> CREATOR =
          new Parcelable.Creator<Bird>() {

     @Override
     public Bird createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
          //Log.i(ReferenceGuide.LOGTAG, "createFromParcel");
          return new Bird(source);
     }

     @Override
     public Bird[] newArray(int size) {
          //Log.i(ReferenceGuide.LOGTAG, "newArray");
          return new Bird[size];
     }
};
```

Edit: Here is logcat output:

```
02-28 15:43:38.048: W/dalvikvm(16350): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cfe468)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at com.example.birdnote.ReferenceGuide.onListItemClick(ReferenceGuide.java:89)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1150)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:4397)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2985)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3671)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
02-28 15:43:38.058: E/AndroidRuntime(16350):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit 2: 
The code where I set up `Birds`:

```
private List<Bird> birds;

// create reference to database
BirdsDataSource datasource;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reference_guide);

   // open connection to db
    datasource = new BirdsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    // get list of birds from db 
    List<Bird> birds = datasource.findAll();  
    if(birds.size() == 0) {
        createData();
        birds = datasource.findAll();
    }

    // set view adapter
    ArrayAdapter<Bird> adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, birds);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The list view populates fine from the database using `Birds`

Comment: add full log cat to know exact problem.

Comment: can you post the logcat log please?

Comment: Which line of onListItemClick is line 89?

Comment: I think "birds" is null

Comment: Line 89 is blank! It's the line after I declare a bird object and before new Intent.

Comment: I think we all agree that `birds` seems to be null.  What did you put into your list?  Can we see the code where you set up the ListView?

Comment: Thanks guys, @G.BlakeMeike I've added the ListView set up

Comment: I forgot to show the constructor in the model...

Comment: clean your project, i don't android is that mad to show an empty line as the cause for an exception

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

`Bird bird = birds.get(position);`

by

`Bird bird = (Bird)l.getAdapter().getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Eclipse wouldn't allow me to do that. I had to change 'l.getListAdapter' to 'l.getAdapter' and then add a cast. Tested and got similar error (uncaught exception). Thanks again..